# Adding an option to a PHP Curl resource

Tags: php, curl

The instructions I have for using an api gives two options.
One requires a zipCode input and one does not.
Using PHP I have successfully built a curl resource using curl_setop for the case that uses the zipCode but not the case that omits the zipCode. The case without the zipCode is supposed to have an extra option after the URL.

All I have been given for instructions is that the curl should be like:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "authToken:12345" https://connect.apisite.com/api/v1/users -d'
[{
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Smith",
"emailAddress": {
"address": "johnsmith@test.com"
}
}]'
```

for the case without the zipCode
and with the zipCode

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H 
"authToken:12345" https://connect.apisite.com/api/v1/users '
[{
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Smith",
"emailAddress": { "address": "johnsmith@test.com" },
"homeAddress" : { "postalCode" : "48124" }
}
}]'
```

My problem is that I do not know how to add the -d  to the curl resource that appears in the first case just after the URL
This works for me:

```
$url = "https://connect.apisite.com/api/v1/users";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'authToken: ' . $authResponse;
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I tried just appending the -d to the URL as

```
$url = "https://connect.apisite.com/api/v1/users  -d";
```

That did not work.

My guess is there is a constant I need to use like

```
curl_setop($ch, CURLOPT_XXXXX, '-d');
```

but I do not know what CURLOPT_XXXX should be.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');` as your call structure seems could be done by a regular POST call which could be handled by:

`curl_setopt(CURLOPT_POST, true);`

which in turn will call the `-d` flag of cURL as per PHP document:

> **CURLOPT_POST**: TRUE to do a regular HTTP POST. This POST is the normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` kind, most commonly used by HTML forms.

Also, you need to change `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);` because doing this will make cURL to pass the data as `multipart/form-data`. Instead, structure your data as a URL-encoded string, something like

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode(json_encode($postData)));`

(*note: I haven't tested the latter line above but you can test it and adjust as per your requirements*), as per PHP documentation note:

> Note:
>
> Passing an array to **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS** will encode the data as multipart/form-data, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Maybe I made the question too complicated. I used the code I showed because that is what I was given when I joined the project.  I am sure your suggestions will make the code better, but what adds the -d option that needs to be sent when the data does not have the zip code. The data structure I have was not what is used I copied and pasted from the instructions I was given.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions.

As was mentioned I did not need to do anything to add the -d

I got the response I need using the following for postData
$postData = json_encode(array(array('emailAddress' => $emailObj, 'firstName' => $firstName, 'lastName' => $lastName)));

or

$postData = json_encode(array(array('emailAddress' => $emailObj, 'firstName' => $firstName, 'lastName' => $lastName, 'homePostalAddress' => $homePostalObj)));

Answer (score -1):

In both request the method is POST, as the previous answer you can set CURLOPT_POST option.  I see the only different is about the data you are sending, in one without zipCode and another with. So, you can just prepare the data before including the zipCode or not in your array of data. You can try something like below.

```
    $dataRequest = [
                'firstName'    => "John",
                'lastName'     => "Smith",
                'emailAddress'    => [
                    'address' => 'johnsmith@test.com'
                ],
                'homeAddress' => [ //dont send this key in the case you dont want zipCode in the request.
                    'postalCode'=> '48124'
                ],
            ];
$url = "https://connect.apisite.com/api/v1/users";
$authToken = '12345';

$ch   = curl_init();
/**
the idea with urldecode is because some api does not accept the 
encoded urls in your case is not important due your data does not 
contains any url but if tomorrow you want to include smth like 
'customerUrl'=>'https://myhomepage.com' the result of http_build_query 
will be like 'https%3A%2F%2Fmyhomepage.com'
*/
$data = urldecode(http_build_query($dataRequest));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$authToken}:");

$headers   = [];
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
/**
HANDLE RESPONSE, CHECK FOR PROPER HTTP CODE DEPENDING OF THE API RESPONSE, 
IN YOUR CASE I GUESS IS CREATE USER YOUR GOAL, SO MAYBE RESPONSE IS 'HTTP_CREATED'
BUT IF THIS FUNCTION WILL BE GENERIC BETTER SWITCH LIKE THIS:

switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
    case Response::HTTP_OK:
    case Response::HTTP_CREATED:
    case Response::HTTP_ACCEPTED:
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        break;
    default:
        $response = [];
}
*/       
}
curl_close($ch);

return $response;
```

This example is with content-type not in json format, you can change it if is requirement of api.

Comment: sorry, you got too much wrong here (the post data, the content type, and the data encoding), had to downvote

Comment: I wasn’t asking about the post data and the content type. I only need to know how to send the -d option when the post data does not have a zip code element. Maybe I should call the -d a switch or flag rather than an option.

Comment: You dont need to add -d option, just change your data including or not the zipCode, the rest of options should be the same, try in that way. I already tested with vouchers api, and its works...